# XSLT infinite template recursion in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am using the XSLT processor available in PHP to transform an XML file. When my XML file is a sample file everything is ok but when I try to process a file with something like 1000 lines I have this error:

`Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): xsltApplyXSLTTemplate: A potential infinite template recursion was detected. You can adjust xsltMaxDepth (--maxdepth) in order to raise the maximum number of nested template calls and variables/params (currently set to 3000)`

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <teiHeader xml:lang="en" />
  <text>
    <body>
      <div type="chapter" n="1">
        <p>
          <s xml:id="e_1">In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.</s>         
        </p>
        <p>
          <s xml:id="e_2">"Whenever you feel like criticizing any one," he told me, "just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had."</s>
        </p>
        </body>
  </text>
</TEI>
```

and my XSLT treatment is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl set">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:div">
    <xsl:call-template name="split-chapter">
        <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="tei:p/tei:s"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="split-chapter">
    <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
    <xsl:param name="limit" select="300"/>
    <xsl:param name="remaining-nodes" select="dummy-node"/>
    <!-- 1. Calculate the total length of nodes -->
    <xsl:variable name="lengths">
        <xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
            <length>
                <xsl:value-of select="string-length()" />
            </length>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="total-length" select="sum(exsl:node-set($lengths)/length)" />
    <!-- 2. Process the chapter: -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- If chapter is too long and can be shortened ... -->
        <xsl:when test="$total-length > $limit and count($nodes) > 1">
            <!-- ... try again with one node less. -->
            <xsl:call-template name="split-chapter">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[not(position()=last())]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="remaining-nodes" select="$remaining-nodes | $nodes[last()]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- Otherwise create a chapter with the current nodes ... -->
            <div type="chapter" n="{@n}" length="{$total-length}" >
                <!-- ... list the paras participating in this chapter ... -->
                <xsl:for-each select="$nodes/parent::tei:p">
                    <p>
                        <!-- ... and process the nodes still left in each para. -->
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="set:intersection(tei:s, $nodes)"/>
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
            <!-- Then process any remaining nodes. -->
            <xsl:if test="$remaining-nodes">
                <xsl:call-template name="split-chapter">
                    <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$remaining-nodes"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is this the input you're using? The example shown isn't well-formed, a closing `</div>` is missing.

Comment: "*I try to process a file with something like 1000 lines*" Could you provide more details? Like how many sentences does the longest chapter have, and what is the average length of a sentence? I believe the worst case scenario here is `(n^2+n)/2` calls, where `n` is the number of sentences in a chapter. If you have a chapter with 100 sentences, and **all** of these are longer than the limit, it will take 5,050 recursive calls to process the chapter.

Comment: @Chester Mc Allister: Did you manage to find a solution to your transformation problem? I'm curious how your chapter-splitter lastly is working.

Answer (score 0):

well, recursion is too expensive, so let us try without:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="tei">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="limit" select="300"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tei:div">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:p[1]" mode="starter"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tei:p" mode="starter">
        <xsl:variable name="length" select="string-length(.)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="theFewNext">
            <xsl:call-template name="followersUptoLimit">
                <xsl:with-param name="path" select="."/>
                <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <div type="chapter" n="{count($theFewNext/tei:p)}" 
             length="{string-length($theFewNext)}" xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
             <xsl:apply-templates select="$theFewNext"/>
        </div>

        <xsl:apply-templates 
           select="following-sibling::tei:p[count($theFewNext/tei:p)]"
           mode="starter"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- gather following elements as long resulting length is lower than limit -->
    <xsl:template name="followersUptoLimit">
        <xsl:param name="length"/>
        <xsl:param name="path"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$path"/>
        <xsl:variable name="nlength" 
             select="$length + string-length($path/following-sibling::tei:p[1])"/>
        <xsl:if test="$nlength &lt; $limit and $path/following-sibling::tei:p[1]">
            <xsl:call-template name="followersUptoLimit">
                <xsl:with-param name="path" select="$path/following-sibling::tei:p[1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$nlength"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The idea is the following:

The stylesheet gathers some `tei:p` elements up to the length-limit into a variable (`$theFewNext`). This variable is printed to output and then the template skips over to the next `tei:p` after those we handled before. With this one, gathering starts again.

I hope the result is just what you need. In my tests the transformation scaled well with the number of elements, even 1.000 have been transformed immediately. The only thing I'm not sure with, is the attribute `div/@n`. This is actually filled with the number of `tei:p` elements within that `div`.